# Android. Can't clear or replace extras

Tags: android, android-intent, extra

I lunch activity from notification.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); 
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP );
notificationIntent.putExtra(GCM_EXTRA_ID, id);
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

If activity destroyed, intent creates new activity and call in oncreate activity this code

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if(extras != null){
    if(extras.containsKey(GCMIntentService.GCM_EXTRA_ID))
    {
        int id = extras.getInt(GCMIntentService.GCM_EXTRA_ID);
        Toast.makeText(this, "GCM_EXTRA_ID ACTIVITY ON CREATE:" + Integer.toString(id) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dbClassItem = new DBClass(this);
        db =  dbClassItem.getWritableDatabase();
        DBClass.setLocateValue(db, id);
        db.close();
        getIntent().putExtra(GCMIntentService.GCM_EXTRA_ID, 0);
    }
}
```

If I close activity by back button and start activity again application still see, that intent has extra with key `GCMIntentService.GCM_EXTRA_ID` *(this is a public static string)*.

How can I clear or replace this extra for next app start. `getIntent().removeExtra()`, `getIntent().getExtras().clear(),getIntent().putExtra(GCMIntentService.GCM_EXTRA_ID, 0)` does not work. What can I do ? Activity has  `android:launchMode ="singleTop"` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved by using onNewIntent instead of using onCrete in Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
       notificationIntent.putExtra(GCM_EXTRA_ID, null);
```

Comment: But i need to clear extras in OnCreate. I will try to use you code like "getIntent().putExtra(GCMIntentService.GCM_EXTRA_ID, null);".Hope  it will works, but I do not think so ...