# Bundle not cleared

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle

I have weird problem. How a Bundle can not be cleared after calling its method **clear()**
This is my code :

```
if(isFromPushNotif) {
                        Bundle pushNotifBundle = getIntent().getExtras() ;
                        Log.i("SplashScreen"," before clear "+pushNotifBundle);
                        intent.putExtras(pushNotifBundle) ;
                        getIntent().getExtras().clear();
                        Log.i("SplashScreen"," after clear "+getIntent().getExtras()); //Here bundle is not cleared , log displays all the initial elements

                    }

startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
finish();
```

Comment: post the value of bundle `here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Try this

- clear your `bundle`

  ```
   getIntent().removeExtra("your_key_here_to_be_removed");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the accepted answer here [Android. Can't clear or replace extras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766249/android-cant-clear-or-replace-extras)

> This problem was solved by using onNewIntent instead of using onCrete in Activity.